# sqlite : update record using value in another table

Tags: sqlite

As sqlite do not support join table
I have a stock table:
stock(TEXT) Price(TEXT)  PriceInUSD(to be updated)
e.g. Apple "USD 100"  NULL
     Orange "HKD 50" NULL

and another exchangeRate table
Currency Rate
e.g. USD 1
HKD 0.13

How can I set PriceInUSD to (substr(Price,5) * exchangeRate.Rate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a sub query

```
update stock 
set priceInUSD=
    (select substr(stock.price,5)*Rate
     from exchangeRate where substr(stock.price,1,3)=Currency )
```